# Troubleshoot duplicating files and renaming based off of a list generated from excel in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlrd

I am trying to write script that will read a file name from a specific cell in Excel, find that file in the folder, and duplicate the file x times while renaming each file from a list of new file names in column A in the same Excel file.

When I run the code below, it works and loops through the tabs and creates the renamed files, but it isn't creating all of the files it says it is.  On the first tab of the document, there are 54 rows with file names in the first column, but the program only creates 27 of the 54 files.

Code:

```
import shutil
import xlrd
active_tab = 0
count_oftabs = 5
while active_tab <= count_oftabs:

#create a python list of all of the file names
#***MANUALLY UPDATE row below: enter 'path of file to copy' within parentheses
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('/Users/optimad 1/Desktop/python-test/utm.xls')
#row below selects which tab within workbook. 0 = 1st tab, 1 = 2nd tab
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(active_tab)
#row below selects which column on the sheet. 0 = 1st column
mylist = ws.col_values(0)
n = 1

row_count = int(len(mylist))-1

#loop through mylist of file names and create and rename files 
while n <= row_count:
    #use new file name from mylst
    file_name = mylist[n]
    #populate name of file to be copied on each tab in cell C1
    see_cell = ws.cell_value(0,2)
    file_to_copy = f'{see_cell}'
    new_file = f'{file_name}.png'
    #create a copy of the file
    shutil.copyfile(file_to_copy, new_file)
    n+=1
n -= 1
print(f'{n} files created and named')
active_tab += 1
```

```
I keep getting this error: 

>Traceback (most recent call last):
>File "create_from_workbook.py", line 35, in <module>
>see_cell = ws.cell_value(0,2)
>File >"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site->packages/xlrd/sheet.py", line 420, in cell_value
>return self._cell_values[rowx][colx]
>IndexError: list index out of range

Any help would be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Less than expected files will be created if there are duplicate names in one or any worksheets or even if there are any blank lines.

When posting code please make sure the indentation is correct: In your code the first "while" block should be indented.

See where I have made some corrections to the code (search for "NOTE")

The error message you are getting is because your code attempted to open an extra worksheet!

I used an Excel file with 2 sheets in the below code and it worked fine.

```
import shutil
import xlrd
active_tab = 0
count_oftabs = 2

# NOTE: Use < rather than <=. This is what is causing the error
#while active_tab <= count_oftabs:
while active_tab < count_oftabs:

    #create a python list of all of the file names
    #***MANUALLY UPDATE row below: enter 'path of file to copy' within parentheses
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls')
    #row below selects which tab within workbook. 0 = 1st tab, 1 = 2nd tab
    ws = wb.sheet_by_index(active_tab)
    #row below selects which column on the sheet. 0 = 1st column
    mylist = ws.col_values(0)
    # NOTE: Start from 0 if the file names starts in the top-left cell.
    # n = 1
    n = 0

    # NOTE: int() is superfluous
    #row_count = int(len(mylist))-1
    row_count = len(mylist)-1

    #loop through mylist of file names and create and rename files
    while n <= row_count:
        #use new file name from mylst
        file_name = mylist[n]
        #populate name of file to be copied on each tab in cell C1
        see_cell = ws.cell_value(0,2)
        file_to_copy = f'{see_cell}'
        new_file = f'{file_name}.png'
        #create a copy of the file
        shutil.copyfile(file_to_copy, new_file)
        n+=1
    # NOTE: Remove this if n starts at 0
    # n -= 1
    print(f'{n} files created and named')
    active_tab += 1
```